# Math question efficiency

Tags: physics

A solar collector has 1000 Btu/min of radiant energy available on a clear sunny day. The collector can transfer 450 Btu/min to a storage tank. What is the efficiency of the system?

I used n= energy-output/energy-input *100

I plugged it all in $\;\dfrac{450}{1000}*\times 100\%$.

I got $45\%$, however on my answer choices it says the answer is $48\%$?

Exact Question. Maybe I used the wrong formula?

> A solar collector has 1000 Btu/min of radiant energy available on a clear sunny day. The collector can transfer 450 Btu/min to a storage tank. What is the efficiency of the system?
>
> A.  17% 
>   B.  25% 
>   C.  37% 
>   **D.  48%**

Comment: There is a typo somewhere. Your calculation is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the correct formula, and **your** calculation is the correct answer: $45\%$.

There must be a misprint/typo in the solution manual/text.

Comment: I'll ask the teacher on Wednesday.

Comment: You did everything correctly, so no worries with your answer. Yes, tell the teacher. S/he will want to know!

Comment: Nice for OP to get ack! +1